# Spring Boot property file externalized through swarm

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-swarm

Is it possible to have my external property files saved using docker swarm and accessed it by my application? Something like a volume that my service/workers can access? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Within docker swarm, the most "swarm" option is to use Docker secrets.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

Docker volumes do not travel across swarm nodes, whereas secrets will be stored at the swarm level, and any container will be able to access them.

The documentation outlines how you can create a swarm secret with a property file, and then drop that property file inside the container where needed.